# appletviewer command not working

Tags: java

This is my MyApplet.java file

```
 import java.applet.*;
  import java.awt.Graphics;

  public class MyApplet{
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawString("shubh,...",20,20);
}
}
```

This is my MyApplet.html file

```
 <html>
   <applet code = "MyApplet.class" width="200" height="100">
   </applet>
     </html>
```

[This is snapshot of cmd when i am trying to use applet viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMnrx.jpg)

Appletviewer is generated but it is blank. Can you please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You class must `extends Applet` class.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MyApplet extends Applet{
 public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
    g.drawString("shubh,...",20,20);
 }
}
```